How to have multiple types of values (keyword, date..) in same name field in Opensearch
I collect the all container log by using OpenSearch.
sometimes, the log has different type value like this.
ex1)
{
"name": "david",
"age": "20"
}
ex2)
{
"name": "david",
"age": 20
}
I know that the data modeling or mapping design process needs to be modified.
But, It takes a lot of time, and I don't have clearance about that :(
So I want to save all of data regardless of data type.
Is it possible to save it by using Muti-field function and Ingest pipeline? (with same field name).
plz let me know the good way to solve it.
Thanks.

I guess you are looking for convert processor:
POST _ingest/pipeline/_simulate
{
  "pipeline": {
    "description": "debug",
    "processors": [
      {
        "convert": {
          "field": "end",
          "type": "integer"
        }
      }
    ]
  },
  "docs": [
    {
      "_index": "banana",
      "_type": "_doc",
      "_id": "125468",
      "_score": 1,
      "_source": {
        "end": 2000
      }
    },
    {
      "_index": "banana",
      "_type": "_doc",
      "_id": "125468",
      "_score": 1,
      "_source": {
        "end": "2000"
      }
    }
  ]
}

The example you shared above will work without issue. The mapping will be keyword only. In the example I gave above, the mapping will be long. But, whenever you sent a value which could not cast to integer, you will get an error like :
unable to convert [2000-01-01] to integer

